# My csrf token refreshes every time the app boots on my vapor app

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I just deployed an application using docker to vapor. The app is up but I am never able to persist a session because when I log csrf_token() method in my service provider boot method, every time a request gets through and the app gets booted it's a new csrf token. I have searched for days why this could happen but haven't gotten any explanation. Any help would be appreciated.

I have set the SESSION_LIFETIME variable on the .env but it does not change anything

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm experiencing a similar issue. After logging into my app I make a JS Fetch POST using the "X-CSRF-Token" header.

I've verified I that the `csrf-token` contains a proper token, but the first POST request always returns a 419 on Vapor.

If I refresh that very same page and try again it works successfully. So strange. One thing I did notice when comparing the HTTP POST request sent the first time that got a 419 against the HTTP POST request sent the second time after I refreshed the page their is a different "XSRF-TOKEN" cookie sent the second time.

Comment: Not yet. It seems like we are having exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your login page should make this request when it mounts

```
axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {});
```

You also need to make sure you have axios withCredentials set to true probably in your bootstrap.js.

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

For your SESSION_LIFETIME are you setting it in your .env.production or whichever environment you are deploying to?

You also may need to check what you SESSION_DRIVER is set to in the same file

```
vapor env:pull staging //for example to see what you have
```

Comment: I am not using axios. I know the csrf token refreshes because I have an info log on a service provider that boots with the app everytime a request is called and for every request called the csrf token is different

Comment: How are you authenticating and how do you persist the session?(Redis,cookie??)